# Incompatible types when using TransformControls with TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want to use the TransformControls addon from Three.js and I'm also using TypeScript for my project. I can include the corresponding files, but when I want to add the controls to the scene I get the following error:

> Argument of type 'TransformControls' is not assignable to parameter of
> type 'Object3D'.   The types returned by 'attach(...)' are
> incompatible between these types.
> Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'Object3D'.

How can I solve this problem?

Relevant code snippets:

```
import * as THREE from "../vendor/three/build/three.module.js";
import { OrbitControls } from "../vendor/three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js";
import { TransformControls } from "../vendor/three/examples/jsm/controls/TransformControls.js";

const transformControls = new TransformControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
transformControls.attach(footScanObject);
scene.add(transformControls);
```

TransformControls.d.ts:

```
import { Camera, Object3D } from '../../../src/Three';

export class TransformControls extends Object3D {
  constructor(camera: Camera, domElement: HTMLElement);

  enabled: boolean;
  axis: string | null;
  mode: string;
  translationSnap: number | null;
  rotationSnap: number | null;
  scaleSnap: number | null;
  space: string;
  size: number;
  userData: { [key: string]: any };

  attach(object: Object3D): void;
  detach(): void;
  setMode(mode: string): void;
  setSpace(space: string): void;
  setSize(size: number): void;
  setSnap(snap: number): void;
  setTranslationSnap(translationSnap: number | null): void;
  setRotationSnap(rotationSnap: number | null): void;
  setScaleSnap(scaleSnap: number | null): void;
  dispose(): void;
}
```

The console states that

> Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module
> '../vendor/three/examples/jsm/controls/TransformControls.js' does not
> provide an export named 'TransformControls'

but at the end of the TransformControls.js file there's this line:

```
export { TransformControls, TransformControlsGizmo, TransformControlsPlane };
```

Comment: @Dale I edited the post for better readability

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me the line

```
attach(object: Object3D): void;
```

is the issue and can't be assigned void.  You have to have a real object.  I would make a generic 3D object and assign it there to start off with.  According to the first error you showed me I would see how that reacts.

```
attach(object: Object3D): Object3D {
  this.add(object);
  return object;
}
```

or in your case, you just have the signature there...

```
attach(object: Object3D): Object3D
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but can you explain it a little bit more or show me a simple example? I'm a newbie to Three.js and don't really know what do you mean about this

Comment: attach(object: Object3D): void;    needs to change accordingly, as I was showing above.  Three.js versions change OFTEN, so be careful about updating the version you are working with or be VERY familiar with what changes took place so you can update your code to meet those changes.